# Centring header row only in tabularx

Tags: tables, align, tabularx

I created the following table

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
...

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|X}
\hline
Advantages & Disadvantages \\
\hline
Test & Test \\
Test & Test \\
Test & Test \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

How can I center-align only the "Advantages" and "Disadvantages" entries in their respective columns and leave all other entries left-aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can centre the text in the p column with

```
 \centering\arraybackslash Advantages
```

or  use a c column cell for the heading

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Advantages}
```